# How do I compute the number of people in closed form for the birthday problem?

Tags: probability

Given that there are $d$ days in a year, I want to compute how many people $n$ are required to be in a room for the probability $P$ of there existing people in the room that share the same birthday to be over 0.5.

$$
P = 1 - \prod_{i = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{d - i}{d}
$$

This means I want to solve the equation

$$
0.5 = 1 - \prod_{i = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{d - i}{d}
$$

And then ceil(n).

How do I solve this equation? Is there a closed form for it? I can just keep trying out numbers, but that’s not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get a closed form approximation. I think that approximation can be tweaked to arbitrary accuracy, but it seems close from the start.

You want the product to be 0.5. Take the natural log of both sides, the product becomes a sum. That sum has a first order Taylor presentation, ln(1-i/d) is about (-i/d). Summing from 0 to n-1, you get -n(n-1)/(2d). Solve the resulting quadratic equation.

2dln(2)=n(n-1).

If you don't want to solve the equation, a good approximation is sqrt(2dln(2))+1.

This is pretty accurate for the classical birthday problem. If d is 365, n is about 22.5.